# How to make knockout to populate data on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout to build a HTML table

```
        <!-- ko foreach: currentPageQuestions -->
                <tr>
                    <td class="question-item" data-bind="html:questionText"></td>
                </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
```

Then I'm trying to paginate this table using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

Like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#dataTableQuestions').DataTable();
    });
```

As the Table is not loaded completely, DataTables script is not finding any elements at the page load and not paginating it.

When I see HTML by clicking on "View Source" I see same HTML(with Knockout code) without TRs or TDs for all the elements in the observable collection.

I can see all the TRs and TDs when I do "Inspect the element" though.

So, just wondering if there's a way to make data available before the code in document.ready function call is triggered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd guess you need a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) to handle interaction between a UI-based plugin like datatables and KnockoutJS. However, I noticed [the datatables.net website suggests a different approach](http://datatables.net/dev/knockout/).

Comment: Please read the answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a bind handler to do this, it will be more maintainable and any change in the data source will reflected in the view, see an example in the snippet bellow:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach = {
 page: 0,
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
      ko.unwrap(options.data);
      if(options.dataTableOptions.paging){
     valueAccessor().data.subscribe(function (changes) {
         var table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable();
            ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page = table.page();
            table.destroy();
        }, null, 'arrayChange');          
      }
        var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes, 0);
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(nodes, function (node) {
         if (node && node.nodeType !== 1) {
             node.parentNode.removeChild(node); 
            }
        });
        return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {        
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
            key = 'DataTablesForEach_Initialized';
        ko.unwrap(options.data);
        var table;
        if(!options.dataTableOptions.paging){
          table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable();
         table.destroy();
        }
        ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
        table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable(options.dataTableOptions);
        if (options.dataTableOptions.paging) {
           if (table.page.info().pages - ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page == 0) 
               table.page(--ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page).draw(false);                
           else 
               table.page(ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page).draw(false);                
        }        
        if (!ko.utils.domData.get(element, key) && (options.data || options.length))
            ko.utils.domData.set(element, key, true);
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
}; 

// Person ViewModel
 var Person = function (data, parent) {
     var that = this;
     this.id = data.id;
     this.isEdit = ko.observable(false);
     this.first = ko.observable(data.first);
     this.last = ko.observable(data.last);
     this.age = ko.observable(data.age);
     this.editButtonText = ko.computed(function () {
         return that.isEdit() ? 'Save' : 'Edit';
     });
     this.full = ko.computed(function () {
         return this.first() + " " + this.last();
     }, this);

     // Subscribe a listener to the observable properties for the table
     // and invalidate the DataTables row when they change so it will redraw


 };
 //Main ViewModel
 var ViewModel = new function () {
         var that = this;
         this.people = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
        
         this.inline = ko.observable(true);
         this.add = function () {
             $('#dialog').dialog('open');
         };
         this.getEditMode = ko.computed(function () {
             return that.inline() ? '(Inline)' : '(Dialog)';
         });
         this.remove = function (person, event) {
             that.people.remove(person);
         };
       this.removeAll = function(person, event){
           that.people.removeAll();  
         };
         this.edit = function (person, event) {
             if (that.inline()) {
                 if (person.isEdit()){
                     person.isEdit(false);
                 }
                 else{
                     that.people().forEach(function(p){
                         if(p.isEdit()){
                             p.isEdit(false);
                         }
                     });
                     person.isEdit(true);
                 }
             } else {
                 $('#editdialog').data('id', person.id);
                 $('#editName').val(person.first());
                 $('#editLast').val(person.last());
                 $('#editAge').val(person.age());
                 $('#editdialog').dialog('open');
             }
         };
     };

 var count = 3;

 // Initial data set
 var data = [{
     id: 1,
     first: "Allan",
     last: "Jardine",
     age: 86
 }, {
     id: 2,
     first: "Bob",
     last: "Smith",
     age: 54
 }, {
     id: 3,
     first: "Jimmy",
     last: "Jones",
     age: 32
 }];


 $(document).ready(function () {

     // Convert the data set into observable objects, and will also add the
     // initial data to the table
     ko.mapping.fromJS(
     data, {
         key: function (data) {
             return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.id);
         },
         create: function (options) {
             return new Person(options.data, ViewModel);
         }
     },
     ViewModel.people);



     $('#dialog').dialog({
         modal: true,
         autoOpen: false,
         height: 350,
         width: 460,
         buttons: {
             'Add Person': function () {

                 ViewModel.people.push(new Person({
                     id: ++count,
                     first: $('#Name').val(),
                     last: $('#Last').val(),
                     age: $('#Age').val()

                 }, ViewModel));
                 $('#ID').closest('div').find('input').val('');
                 $(this).dialog('close');
             },
                 'Close': function () {
                 $(this).dialog('close');
             }
         }
     });

     $('#editdialog').dialog({
         modal: true,
         autoOpen: false,
         height: 350,
         width: 460,
         buttons: {
             'Edit Person': function () {
                 var id = $(this).data('id');

                 ko.utils.arrayForEach(ViewModel.people(), function (person) {

                     if (id == person.id) {
                         person.first($('#editName').val());
                         person.last($('#editLast').val());
                         person.age($('#editAge').val());

                     }
                 });

                 $('#editName').closest('div').find('input').val('');
                 $(this).dialog('close');
             },
                 'Close': function () {
                 $(this).dialog('close');
             }
         }
     });

     ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);





     $('#AddPerson').click(function () {

         ViewModel.people.push(new Person({
             id: ++count,
             first: 'NEW',
             last: 'NEW',
             age: '99'

         }, ViewModel));


     });





 });
```

```css
.ui-buttonset .ui-button {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

body{
  background:white;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.3.5/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>



<button data-bind="click: add">ADD</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;Toggle Editing Mode <span data-bind="text: getEditMode"></span>

<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: inline" />
<br />
<br/>
    <button data-bind="click: removeAll">Remove All</button>
    <br />
<br />
<div id="wrapper">
    <table id="example" style="width:100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>                
                <th>Remove</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <!-- you can also pass the dataTablesForEach option as a bind to let the HTML more clean -->
        <!-- like this: <tbody data-bind="dataTablesForEach: dataTableOptions"> -->
        <tbody data-bind="dataTablesForEach: {data: people, dataTableOptions: {
                          jQueryUI: true,
                          scrollY: 250,
                          paging: true,
                          dom: 'rtip',
                          columns:[
                              {width: '30px'},
                              {width: '100px'},
                              {width: '100px'},
                              {width: '100px'},
                              {width:'100px'}
                          ]
                      }
                  }">
            <tr style="height:50px;">
                <td><span data-bind="text: id" />
                </td>
                <td style="width:50px;"> <span data-bind="text: first, visible:!isEdit()"></span>

                    <input class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="textInput: first, visible: isEdit()" style="width:95%" />
                </td>
                <td> <span data-bind="text: age, visible:!isEdit()"></span>

                    <input class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="textInput: age, visible: isEdit()" style="width:95%" />
                </td>
               
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: $parent.remove">Remove</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"   data-bind="click: $parent.edit, text: editButtonText, css: {'btn-success': isEdit}"></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>
        <button id="AddPerson">ADD</button>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div>
        <textarea rows="20" cols="100" data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data.people, null, 2)"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="dialog" title="Add New Person" style="display:none">
        <label for="Name">First Name</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
        <br />
        <label for="Last">Last Name</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="Last" id="Last" />
        <br />
        <label for="Age">Age</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="Age" id="Age" />
        <br />
    </div>
    <div id="editdialog" title="Edit Person" style="display:none">
        <label for="editName">First Name</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="editName" id="editName" />
        <br />
        <label for="editLast">Last Name</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="editLast" id="editLast" />
        <br />
        <label for="editAge">Age</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="editAge" id="editAge" />
        <br />
    </div>
```

> Any question about how binding handlers works see the documentation about, 
>   in the Knockout web site: [Custom Bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)